# Windows file explorer thumbnails

Tags: windows, thumbnails, explorer

I have a research task to be able to save the thumbnail images of Office documents, PDF files, images, etc... I am working with the Windows API Code Pack where i can easily retrieve the thumbnail image that is shown in Windows File Explorer.

This is how i do it:

1. I create a new word document on my laptop (Office installed of
   course).
2. in Word, the setting to save the thumbnail in the file is checked
3. Upon saving, i can see the thumbnail in the file explorer (as
   expected)

Now i copy the file to my local VM (Windows Server 2012) where NO office is installed
There **i can still see the thumbnail** that was generated although the icon is the WordPad icon (which opens the documents).

Now when i copy the same file to our servers (Windows Server 2016) where NO office is installed
There **i can not see the thumbnails** that were generated...

I went through all resources i found 
Setting the folder view options to show thumbnails (no luck)
Already deleted the thumbnail cache (no luck)

Is there some article/resource describing the windows server 2016 support for thumbnail images in windows file explorer? Any other ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Whether or not File Explorer shows thumbnails depends on whether or not a [thumbnail handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144118.aspx) shell extension is available.

Comment: Tnx for your comment. I googled a bit on this and you are surely right. Is there any way to install for example the microsoft office thumbnail handlers without installing office on its whole on the server? It seems that this is the case on my local dev environment. Allthough i have to say that there is a SharePoint installation running there so maybe SharePoint also adds that handler?